How to fix the error No module named 'spire.pdf'
I am getting the following error message when trying to convert PDF as HTML using Python.
The error message that I see is '  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spire.pdf''. Please advise.
   from spire.pdf.common import *
   from spire.pdf import *
   # Create a Document object
   doc = PdfDocument()
   # Load a PDF document
   doc.LoadFromFile("cadernoRC_2024_07_09_v06.pdf")
   # Set the conversion options to 
   convertOptions = doc.ConvertOptions
   # Specify convert options
   convertOptions.SetPdfToHtmlOptions(True, True, 1, True)
   # Save the PDF document to HTML format
   doc.SaveToFile("cadernoRC_2024_07_09_v06.html", FileFormat.HTML)
   # Dispose resources
   doc.Dispose()
  






   ModuleNotFoundError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
   Cell In[1], line 1
   ----> 1 from spire.pdf.common import *
      2 from spire.pdf import *
      4 # Create a Document object
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spire.pdf'


Are you sure it is installed?

Yes, I just confirmed that that package is installed.

Check if this helps: https://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/spire-pdf-for-python-t12628.html

Certainly you did pip install spire to install the module, you need to install Spire.Pdf like this: pip install Spire.Pdf

I used to have this same error, but after I went through the installation guide on the PyPi page, it fixed the error.
